# R Program map of World Leader's Age

Tags: r

I am working on R program to plot color-coded map of world leader's age.

This is my source, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_leaders_in_2015

Question: How do I know which countries are included in R program? I am searching documentation of [rworldmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rworldmap/rworldmap.pdf) but they do not give list.

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the structure of the value returned by the `getMap` function. It appears that column `"NAME"` contains the name of an area in the map while `"SOVEREIGNT"` is the name of the corresponding sovereign state.

The code to extract the unique values in both columns is the following:

```
library(rworldmap)
world_map <- getMap()
areas <- levels(world_map[["NAME"]])
sovereign_states <- levels(world_map[["SOVEREIGNT"]])
```

Comment: Very interesting. Didn't realize the difference between name and sovereign state.